# When an electron and a positron annihilate each other are they deleted from existence entirely? Does this follow the conservation of energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, antimatter

When an electron and a positron annihilate each other and release gamma rays, is that just changing the energy into something else (following the conservation of energy), or is energy actually being lost?

Comment: Yes it follows conservation of energy. The energy of the gamma rays will of course have to equal the kinetic energy of the pair plus the mass energy of the pair.